# jQuery load images from external file with lazy load plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, load, lazy-loading

I'm using [Lazy Load Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) for jQuery to load imgs when page is scrolled. Additionaly I want to load images from gallery to container while user clicks an anchor (to prevent from unnecessary content loading), by .load() function:

```
$('#category_1').load('gallery.php?a=1');
```

My problem is fact, that .load() function strips `<script>` tags from loaded content, and images cannot load using Lazy Load plugin.

```
<img src="blank.gif" data-original="img.png" alt="img" />
<script> $('img').lazyload({ effect : 'fadeIn' }); </script>
```

So, I just thought that I can put `<script>` tags in file where content is loaded, but it doesn't work.

Is anybody meet that kind of issues?
Greetings

Comment: The `.load()` method does strip out `<script>` blocks but it does execute them.

Comment: But it doesn't execute them properly, nothing happens anyway.

Comment: Then there must be some other problem. It executes them perfectly well in my experience.

Comment: I just put `<img>` in gallery.php, after tag put lazyload script, and load gallery.php in index.php to my container, I can't see mistakes too, but It's not working :(

Comment: I heard about .on() and .delegate() functions, but I cannot use them in this case.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it's really hard to say what's wrong. Are you sure you're importing the plugin properly? Are you sure your version of jQuery is new enough?

Comment: That is simplified (without meta tags and other) code of index.php:
http://pastebin.com/A3FBJvwD

and code of gallery.php
http://pastebin.com/RynjjjTs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a callback function to `.load`?

```
$('#category_1').load('gallery.php?a=1', function() {
   $('#category_1 > img').lazyload({ effect : 'fadeIn' });
});
```

**update**
looking at the code you posted on pastebin, it would be on index.php, line 14:

```
$("#loadpic").click(function() { 
    $("#page").load ("gallery.php", function() {
        $("#page").find("img").lazyload({ effect : "fadeIn", skip_invisible : false });
    });
});
```

as [the doc says](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) (at the very bottom), add `skip_invisible:false` to solve your problem

and there would be no javascript on gallery.php

Comment: Still nothing, image is represented by graytext in firebug so it's still hidden.

Comment: I updated the answer according to the code you posted on pastebin (the find part). Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I wrote `src` attribute in image tag to check that content loads at all, and it is, but Lazy load plugin replaces what is under source attribute by `data-original` attribute content, and it's still not working. I heard about `.delegate()` function that executes script on elements dynamically inserted to DOM, but I can't write actual code in this issue.

Comment: did you tried this? `$("img.lazy").lazyload({skip_invisible : false});`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/) to control load order